# Bitcode and enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, enterprise-distribution, bitcode

Since XCode 7 we can export apps from bitcode Which is default when exporting for enterprise distribution. But what does that mean for older iOS versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That BitCode is not supported so user's of your app won't benefit in the way they could if only BitCode would be enabled.

Probably at some point Apple will require to support BitCode (but this is just my guess)

Comment: so iOS 5,6,7 and 8 still can install the ipa's?

Comment: 7 & 8 yes. Verified onmy own. Dont have any 5 or 6 devices at hand. Hate to see an unacepted answer. :)